# 2nd order high pass filter PSPICE error

Tags: filter, error, pspice, ota

I'm working on designing a 2nd order sallen key high pass filter in PSPICE for a school project, but in subthreshold with resistors replaced with OTAs (transamp). Schematics shown in figures below. The two transamps each have a bias current = 100 pA. I've connected it accordingly, but when I simulate, I get the following error:

"Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving V_transamp_2_V1. You may break the loop by adding a series resistance"

I'm not sure why I am getting this error as it is connected the way it should be theoretically

[image: Sallen Key High pass filter]

[image: OTA (subthreshold)]

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you connected in parallel two, or more voltage sources. Looking over the pictures it seems that in addition to the supply, `V1`, you also have `V2` and `V5` -- since you made the supply internal to the subcircuit. Delete `V1` and leave the two outside, only. Better yet, make only one of them as a supply and connnect the two subcircuit instances to that.

---

Just to make sure, the voltage source is, ideally, with a zero internal resistance. If you connect two in parallel, each source will try to ouput a current with the value of its voltage divided by the resistance of the other, which is zero, which cannot be. Similarly for two current sources in series.